# centering individual letters in a vertical string in java

Tags: java, swing, awt, drawstring

Okay so I have a vertical string but when it contains I's or L's they are offset from the rest of the string because of how they are typographically written they are in a sense left justified in the box they are drawn in unlike the rest are drawn centered. I am wondering how to make those letters fall into line with the others. Also of importance is that these are individual drawstring calls. I tried using AffineTransform but it mashes all the letters together. this is the code i use to loop through the string and write each character.

```
for(int i =0; i<team.length();i++) 
{
    gg.drawString(Character.toString(team.charAt(i)), 100, ypos-fm.getDescent());
    ypos+=40;
}
```

The string im using is BOLIVAR if you'd like to test it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) showing you use of `charWidth()`.

Comment: i don't use charWidth.

Comment: How else would you do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try centering the text around the character width

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class TestVerticalTexr {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestVerticalTexr();
    }

    public TestVerticalTexr() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            String team = "BOLIVAR";
            FontMetrics fm = g2d.getFontMetrics();
            int ypos = fm.getHeight();
            for (int i = 0; i < team.length(); i++) {
                int x = 100 - (fm.charWidth(team.charAt(i)) / 2);
                g2d.drawString(Character.toString(team.charAt(i)), x, ypos);
                ypos += fm.getHeight();
            }
            g2d.dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could consider using a [Text Icon](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/04/02/text-icon/). It is a little more sophisticated in the painting of the text.